# Issue with building a Resizeable Graph/Chart compatible with IE8

Tags: html, css, graph, charts, scale

Now, I have made a bullet graph using pure html and css. No javascript/jquery libraries were used.

The whole HTML page has just the bullet chart with size `1000px * 500px` (almost full page). In my application I also need to display the same chart in roughly `300px * 300px` in some other new page.

Now, I don't want to build another smaller chart for the new page, I just want to be able to reduce the scale of the existing full page version of the chart and reuse it. How do I achieve this?

Comment: **ALERT!!! Need to be able to do this on IE8!!!**

Comment: Please elaborate...if possible some link or something.....Dont mind, but i am against the clock here...so any further suggestion would greatly help

Comment: There is a website that you can input your code into. It is called http://jsfiddle.net  -  We can't tell what you are talking about. This could be quite possibly super simple... but there is no way to tell, if we can't see what you are talking about. a "Bullet chat" is not a common thing.

Comment: I you are building this with ems instead of px, that would be nice to know. Why can't you just make another chart, that is smaller, give it a different class name etc, I would suggest making it responsive, just put a min-width: 300px; max-width: 600px; and it will stretch by itself.... then a media query to change the other stuff... like I said... we are in the dark here... how about a picture of your "chart."

Comment: you can probably just use tables if you need IE 8 -

Comment: done....by making another chart actually....called it "Mini-chart":)

Comment: You should put up your code and answer your question officially so that this thread isn't just a weird mess for future visitors. Your answer is just as confusing as your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS:

```
transform:scale(0.25);         /* IE 10, Firefox */
-webkit-transform:scale(0.25); /* Chrome */
-ms-transform:scale(0.25);     /* IE 9 */
```

Adjust the scale coefficient as needed.

Also note you could use Viewport Units if the fullsize graph has a width like `60%` but note that browser support is currently very low.

```
transform:scale(calc(300px / 60vw));
```

Comment: First, can you please provide any link see the usage of above in action.

Comment: Second, you suggest that i add the whole page as it is and in the css I just do the above change it'll reduce its size??

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TTFhn/). Yes, that should work. It really depends on how you have it set up, exactly, which I can't tell from your question.

Comment: Sorry, not much can be done there. The best you can do is change how the graph is contructed to use percentages, and then you can change the `width` and `height` of the container to "scale" the whole thing.

Comment: oh christ I just checked what you sent on Chrome and started jumping with joy....then tried it on IE8 :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work on IE8, I could not use the transformation scales method suggested by **Kolink**, as it is not supported. So I had to edit a copy of the big chart completely to bring it down to size . If you are using Chrome/Firefox/IE9+ go for **Kolink's** method, it rocks!!